# Get names of nodes with firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am trying to get the keys(nodes names) from firebase.
My db looks like

> xxxxx-heat-xxxx-> contacts ,yoni-alina-12-03-2014,yoni-alex-12-03-2014

the contacts,yoni... are keys and they have array.
I need to get the names of tables... like in this example I should get 
contacts,yoni-alina-12-03-2014,yoni-alex-12-03-2014

Comment: There aren't tables in Firebase. It is just a ref (or a node ).

Comment: yes you right I want to get names of the node

Comment: The Firebase Database SDKs (such as the JavaScript SDK used by Ionic) have no way to only load the keys. In the Firebase Database you either load the entire node or you load none of it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211811/get-firebase-child-nodes-names-without-getting-their-children-too-in-firebase-r