# What is the most efficient way to get a key in RTDB?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’ve been figuring out how to get the key and use it but couldn’t figure it out. Tried Object.keys, nothing good was on YT for it, [Get Firebase child nodes' names without getting their children too in Firebase response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211811/get-firebase-child-nodes-names-without-getting-their-children-too-in-firebase-r), [Firebase REST API working with shallow data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601076/firebase-rest-api-working-with-shallow-data), using .getKey to get the key and store it to then use .update after receiving it etc. I’m probably overthinking it, thanks in advance.

```
firebase
     .database()
     .ref("Posts")
     .push({
          Title: textToSaveTitle,
          Post: textToSave,
          uid: user.uid,
          profilePic: downloadURL,
          firstLast: fln,
          username: username,
          likes:0,
          //flair: 
          document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton").innerHTML,
           time: time + " " + cMonth + "/" + cDay + "/" + cYear
                }).getKey()
                .then(function () {
                  console.log(key);
firebase
     .database()
     .ref("Posts")
     .on("value", function (lists) {
          lists.forEach(function (data) {
            var info = data.val();
            var keys = Object.keys(lists)
            console.log(keys)
```

Comment: Just to clarify you mean after doing snapshot.val(), you want to get the key just like the individual data right? (ex. data.photoLink)

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is you're having. Since you indicated having tried something, please edit your question to include the [minimum, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the keys of the snapshot, you can do so with:

```
firebase
     .database()
     .ref("Posts")
     .on("value", function (lists) {
          let keys = []
          lists.forEach(function (data) {
            keys.push(data.key);
          }
          console.log(keys)
     });
```

Comment: Ahh, I meant more of, getting the individual key so I can save it as the post’s id, I worded it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After setting up the info variable,make another variable and set it equal to data.key to get the key for each of them, should work